# How to fix this problem with 'https' in react native?

Tags: react-native, https, expo

I have some problems to run my app, I try to disable the SSL configuration from fetch methods, but no success yet.
Here bellow some code:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
        const https = require('https');  <--- Here
        const httpsAgent = new 
        https.Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: false});
        var username = this.state.username;
        var password = this.state.password;
          if (username && password) {
            fetch("https://...url here...", {
              method: "POST",
              headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
```

follow error is:

> You attempted attempted to import the Node standard library module
>   "https" from "components\Login.js". It failed because React Native
>   does not include the Node standard library. Read more at
>   https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/faq/#can-i-use-nodejs-packages-with-expo
>   ERROR 12:37 Building JavaScript bundle: error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node-fetch is for nodeJs not react native.. use react-native-fetch https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fetch   or personally I would use axios  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-axios

Comment: Neither of these packages can disable ssl configurations in react native